# Swagger in Nestjs remove hashtag in URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui

I serve Swagger on Nestjs with something like

**main.ts**

```
*****

 const docBuilder = new DocumentBuilder();

  const options = docBuilder
    .setTitle(process.env.npm_package_name)
    .setDescription('WHATEVER')
    .setVersion(process.env.npm_package_version)
    .addBearerAuth()
    .addTag('FOO')
    .build();

  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
  SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document);

*****
```

And then, I can access to my Swagger on

***http://localhost:PORT/api***

***http://localhost:PORT/api/#/swagger-ui.html***

However, for the environment that I have on production and the requirements of the project I would need this url to be without hashtag, like

***http://localhost:PORT/api/swagger-ui.html***

Does anyone know how to customise this URL in Nestjs?

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks in advance